# Psych control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rake, yaml, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using the `yaml_db` gem to migrate my DB from `PHP`/`mySQL` to `RoR`/`Postgres`.  I am getting the above error on line 1555870 (of ~4M) of my input YAML file when I run:

```
bundle exec rake db:data:load RAILS_ENV=production
```

It seems to be line or size dependent - I've narrowed it down to this particular line, which currently has a comment on it:

```
-
  slot_id: '2628865'
  sheet_id: '18485'
  label: '10:20am to 12:20pm'
  name: 'Jim Watson'
  email: ''
#bad here - moving "breakrighthere" before this comment throws error related to bad syntax
breakrighthere
-
  slot_id: '2628866'
  sheet_id: '18485'
  label: '2:35pm to 3:05pm'
  name: 'Christy Brown'
  email: ''
```

The stack trace:

```
rake aborted!
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1
/home/signup/app/releases/11/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/yaml_db.rb:61:in `load_documents'
/home/signup/app/releases/11/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:57:in `block in load'
/home/signup/app/releases/11/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/home/signup/app/releases/11/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/signup/app/releases/11/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/home/signup/app/releases/11/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:56:in `load'
/home/signup/app/releases/11/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:31:in `load'
/home/signup/app/releases/11/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/tasks/yaml_db_tasks.rake:35:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:data:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have some invisible control characters slipped into the YAML? Can you `cat -vet` that chunk of the YAML and see if anything odd shows up?

Comment: Good suggestion @mu but all I see are the '$' line terminators.

Comment: Any reason that you're not just dumping CSVs from MySQL and doing COPYs inside PostgreSQL to load the data? You'd have to rewrite the schema manually but that shouldn't be that difficult. Or maybe look at other tools that don't use YAML, YAML just seems like a very odd choice for a task like this.

Comment: I thought about that but I am not very familiar with `PostgreSQL`.  I wrote a few `sed` rules to transform the file and thought I was home free when I hit this.  I guess I should think seriously about CSVs and COPYs.

Comment: Thanks @mu.  I switched to CSVs and with a little care and some sed/perl commands on the server it looks great.  I appreciate your help - if you enter this as an answer, I would accept.

Comment: I don't feel like I've answered anything though, I just pointed out some possible alternatives. A simple "thanks" is all I deserve here. Now if I had gone chasing through that gem to figure out why it was producing invalid YAML...

Comment: Fair enough @mu.  Thanks again for your great suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, and in hopes to help someone who may see this in the future, it ended up being a whitespace error.

I had opened the file in multiple applications, and it changed the amount of spaces for a tab.

Check spacing first! It's the easiest thing to fix if that ends up being the issue!

Answer (score 1):

The error is misleading, but the example you give is incorrect YAML, and should throw an error in any parser. You can easily check that when feeding the text, [with](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=-%0A%20%20slot_id%3A%20%272628865%27%0A%20%20sheet_id%3A%20%2718485%27%0A%20%20label%3A%20%2710%3A20am%20to%2012%3A20pm%27%0A%20%20name%3A%20%27Jim%20Watson%27%0A%20%20email%3A%20%27%27%0A%23bad%20here%20-%20moving%20%22breakrighthere%22%20before%20this%20comment%20throws%20error%20related%20to%20bad%20syntax%0Abreakrighthere%0A-%0A%20%20slot_id%3A%20%272628866%27%0A%20%20sheet_id%3A%20%2718485%27%0A%20%20label%3A%20%272%3A35pm%20to%203%3A05pm%27%0A%20%20name%3A%20%27Christy%20Brown%27%0A%20%20email%3A%20%27%27&type=python) or [without](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=-%0A%20%20slot_id%3A%20%272628865%27%0A%20%20sheet_id%3A%20%2718485%27%0A%20%20label%3A%20%2710%3A20am%20to%2012%3A20pm%27%0A%20%20name%3A%20%27Jim%20Watson%27%0A%20%20email%3A%20%27%27%0Abreakrighthere%0A-%0A%20%20slot_id%3A%20%272628866%27%0A%20%20sheet_id%3A%20%2718485%27%0A%20%20label%3A%20%272%3A35pm%20to%203%3A05pm%27%0A%20%20name%3A%20%27Christy%20Brown%27%0A%20%20email%3A%20%27%27&type=python) the comment, in some online parser (python based).

The problem is that there should be a dash at the beginning of that unindented line (if the dashes would not be at the beginning of the lines you could alternatively outdent to finish the sequence in block style).

Comment: I think the `breakrighthere` thing is just a marker that was added as a debugging aid, I don't think it is part of the YAML that this tool is dumping.

Comment: @muistooshort I considered that, but I thought in that case the OP could have just commented out that line as well to get the same effect as well. Or just indicate the whole thing in one line: `#in the line before this one here things go wrong`

Comment: Thanks Anthon but @mu is correct.  I guess I should have explained but I thought it was obvious.  I got this useless error message and then figured out where it was occurring by "binary search" using "breakrighthere".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was because I was creating the YAML with a heredoc block, but not disabling interpolation of escape character.

I fixed it by disabling interpolation in the heredoc, by putting the heredoc identifier in single quotes.

From the [docs on heredoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents):

> A heredoc allows interpolation and escaped characters. You may disable interpolation and escaping by surrounding the opening identifier with single quotes

So, this would be an example that has control characters, but doesn't do interpolation (note the single quotes around `'YAML'`):

```rb
    <<~'YAML'
      ---
      foo: '\1BAR\2'
    YAML
```